# On Xcode 7 I keep receiving error "No accounts with iTunes connect access"

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, account, submission, xcode7.1beta

When I try to submit my app with the new seed Xcode 7.1 beta (7B60) I receive a weird error by which it complaints that there is "No accounts with iTunes connect access - iTunes connect access for... is required. Add an account in the Accounts preference pane", while of course the account is there and kicking as you may see in the attached screenshot. I already had to delete all my profiles and restore them again in order to be successfully codesigned, now this. Please tell me how I may fix it.[image]

[image: Technical role added]

[image: Technical role detail]

Comment: Have you tried removing the account from XCode and adding it again?

Comment: Yes, twice, I even tried submitting the app without any account thereafter following their flow for adding the account again.

Comment: And are all your contracts in iTunes Connect in order? (There has been a recent contract update)

Comment: Yes, sure. I check the iTunes Store nearly daily. Now I tried removing it again, closing Xcode and reopening it by following again their tutorial for adding the AppleID, but no way again. That must be a bug with Apple. Of course I also submitted the issue on the Apple Forum.
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/18095

Comment: I do not think people would make much with that. At any rate my priority is now how to return submitting my apps to the app store. I shall care about privacy later.

Comment: @FabrizioBartolomucci : did you solve this problem, i am facing the same issue , if you can help me with this. thanks in advance...

Comment: hello i am also facing the same issue, how can it be solved as i also tried twice to remove and add account again but still i am facing the problem

Comment: Having the same problem after releasing a lot of times before. Workaround for now is using Xcode > OpenDeveloperTool > Application Loader, after exporting from the organizer. I remember last time, removing and adding the account worked, but now it still fails.

Comment: Check this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/46685089/1753005

Comment: I have exactly the same issue and none of the answers worked for me...

Answer (score 35):

For me I had to remove my account from Xcode > preferences > accounts > Apple IDs by pressing the "-" bottom left. Then The "+" and adding back in my details. Nothing to do with Technical accounts being required. As being Admin gives you full access and privileges anyway.

Comment: I did this and it didn't work, then I quit Xcode and re-ran it then it worked.

Answer (score 31):

Remove the Apple ID you're experiencing issues with from your Accounts list. Then, add the Apple ID back to the Accounts list.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me. I also removed other Apple IDs that I'm not using right now, and haven't re-added those yet.

Comment: This also worked for me, however infuriating that error message may be. It seems like nearly all of Apple's errors should be accompanied by "Remove your accounts, clean your build, close Xcode, then start over"

Comment: Also I needed to restart Xcode after adding my account back.

Answer (score 9):

Check System Status here first.   ☞  [***System Status***](https://developer.apple.com/system-status/)

Make sure you click and open the service you want. It could be green but may be down.

In my case although iTune Connect was green, when I clicked to open my account, activity spinner kept going forever.

So actually iTune Connect was a problem.

I waited until I could log into my account, tried to upload binary again from Xcode, than above warning disappeared.

It had nothing to do with my Xcode or my account. It was Apple server.

Comment: Same thing happened today.

Answer (score 8):

Workaround: Export your .IPA for App Store Deployment, then use Application Loader to upload to iTunes Connect.

Comment: This was the only method that worked for me... The Xcode organizer is causing me so much trouble lately, that I do this by default.

Answer (score 7):

I've managed to solve this issue today. The problem was that my developer account was different from my iTunes connect account (Because I'm in different developer teams).

I only had my developer email in Xcode preferences, so adding the iTunes Connect account solved the issue.

Comment: Yep, same here. Interesting to note, that this "iTunes connect" account seems to be empty in account pane (no contracts, etc), but still it works - organizer gets proper data from the real team account, not the added one

Comment: XCode preferences - Acctounts. Just add the iTunes account (Apple id)

Answer (score 7):

In my case I have created **Apple developer account**, but haven't created **iTunes Connect account**

Comment: yes, this can be a common confusion: once you have created an Apple developer account, even if it is Admin, you still have to create an ITC account and at least give it access as an developer

Comment: In my case both the Apple Developer Portal account and iTunes Connect account had been created, but I was only an Admin of the Apple Developer Portal.  I was not added as any role to the iTunes Connect account.

Answer (score 4):

This will happen if you are using an Apple ID that is being shared between teams. So if Apple ID is used for more teams just remove that emails you don't want or create new one.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16159

Answer (score 4):

**I have solved the problem.**

Just turn off Two-factor authentication.

From https://appleid.apple.com

:)

Comment: This was my issue! 

Once I logged into https://appleid.apple.com using Two-factor authentication, I was able to successfully Archive in Xcode again.

It's funny/strange that Xcode wouldn't provide more explanation or instructions how to resolve this issue when its related to Two-factor authentication.

Comment: Finally! I've been trying to solve this all day. Simply logging in to https://appleid.apple.com and answering security questions was exactly my fix.

Comment: Well, that's a great solution. "Just make your account easier to hack". ORLY Apple?

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work for me. However: switching off 2FA allows you to use the ApplicationLoader.

Answer (score 3):

I got this error message when trying to upload using a Beta version of xCode 9 - don't use a beta.

Answer (score 3):

For me (working with XCode 9.3), solution was to close and restart XCode, it worked!

Answer (score 2):

For the time being I am submitting the exported app with Application Loader that seems to be friendlier. When Apple makes up her mind and also fix Xcode I shall take the shortcut.

Comment: As a matter of fact even AL gives a lot of errors based on the fact i useXcode 7.1 instead of 7. I suspect this may also be the cause of the problem about submitting with Xcode. Now I am downloading version 7 and see what happens.

Comment: In fact by using the technical user I may finally submit the binary on XCode 7. So there are two factors: using the technical user and Xcode 7. The same error was provided by not following either.

Comment: It worked well with AL in my case (using an admin account). Strangely, XCode (7.1) worked well a few days ago, using a different account.

Answer (score 2):

First time I faced this problem.

In my case, I just needed to wait and it fixed by itself. I sent two updates, and after successfully submitting the first one, an hour later, I had this error on the next one. I tried what other people said about removing and adding the account, but it didn't work. It's probably something on the side of Apple.

Comment: i am waiting form last 3 days and still i am facing the problem

Comment: having same situation as yours

Comment: finally uploaded successfully by it self

Answer (score 2):

Remove current account you use now, and add back again, that's the only one solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem days ago and I've tried a bunch of solutions and none of them worked for me.

But what I have found is that I'm trying to upload the build using my Macbook connected to the company's guests WiFi and they're using a firewall to prevent uploading or attaching files.

just tried to upload it from anther network that allows uploading and yes it was just as simple as that :D

Answer (score 2):

I was able to still successfully export the app (rather than clicking upload to app store) and signing still worked. Apple also allows you to use something called the Application Loader. I was able to successfully upload this way.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/UploadingBinariesforanApp.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94027/285661) for instructions how to write *better* "link-based" answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As has already been stated by two of the other answers here, note that an **iTunes Connect** account is different to an **Apple Developer** Account. You need to create **both**. Although the **[Apple Developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/UploadingYourApptoiTunesConnect/UploadingYourApptoiTunesConnect.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH36-SW2)** states that you will need to upload to iTunes Connect, it does not explicitly state that you need to register for iTunes Connect **separately**.

This is not obvious when attempting to `Upload` / `Validate` / `Export` an application through Xcode, as this is the first step at which you will need an iTunes Connect account. On top of this, the error message shown when you don't have an iTunes Connect account gives a link entitled `Add account`, though this link simply takes you back to the `Xcode -> Preferences -> Account` tab (which doesn't actually **allow** you to create an iTunes Connect account).

I tried visiting **[iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/)** to create an account, though that page told me that I needed to create an account **before** being able to access iTunes Connect. Considering I was an **`admin`** on a team, I thought I would have permission to do this. However, the critical step that I was missing was buried deep inside the **[iTunes Connect help](https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/dev300c2c5bf)**:

> Initially, only the **team agent** (the person who joins the Apple Developer Program) can sign in to iTunes Connect and perform these steps. [...] If you are the team agent, use the Apple ID you used to join the Apple Developer Program and add other users to your iTunes Connect organization.

Getting the team agent to add me to iTunes Connect (as is described **[here](https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/devdbefef011)**) solved the problem for me; I can now successfully upload, validate and export applications through Xcode.

Hopefully this helps someone else who also didn't realise this!

Answer (score 2):

**I just restarted my mac and its working fine**

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue on my machine that's running the latest version of Xcode on a beta version of OS X. To solve the issue, I archived the app on a different machine running the latest public release of OS X and Xcode, and uploaded it from there. I simply exported my developer account and imported it onto my other machine. The app submitted successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with my account which is on multiple teams.

I had to:

1. Explicitly add the AppleId for the iTunes connect account of the new team (name+email@email.com) on xCode->Preferences.
2. Verify my email for the new iTunes connect account by logging into https://appleid.apple.com.

Error went away after this.

Answer (score 1):

Let me tell you what worked for me.
I was getting the same issue.

Later I figured out that I was using OpenDNS to control my network and when I disabled the OpenDNS it works just fine and the issue got solved.

So, people looking for solution check whether you have firewalls.
Keep it as one of your check lists.

Correct me if I am wrong.

P.S. I also tried the above given solutions but nothing worked for me until I disabled the firewall.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue come up after 470+ successful uploads to iTunes Connect. After deleting my provisioning profiles, revoking my certs, deleting my apple id, and re-adding it to `xCode - Accounts`, without any success, I called the Apple support line... They could not help.

Eventually I had a wild idea to delete myself as an Admin from a DIFFERENT team. It works now. So, for those with this problem, ask yourself if you are part of a different team that could be conflicting.

Answer (score 1):

You may have this problem if your Apple Developer Program Membership has expired.

Just renewing it (and paying 99€) will solve it.

Comment: Have the case for : "The Apple Developer Program Licence Agreement has been updated".

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved it....it is unclear which of the following was key.

1) The contracts section in iTunesConnect was asking for some new banking information (i.e. was my bank account an individual or corporate account).  I answered that.  It took about 10 minutes to 'confirm' - meanwhile I did #2 and #3 below.

2) I deleted my iTunes Account account (myname @ gmail . com) from the accounts on my Mac.  I then added that account back.

3) I quit Xcode and restarted it.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed you seem to have two email accounts listed there - your Gmail and your domain email address.

Which address are you using to log into iTunes Connect? Is this different to the account you use to create provisioning profiles?

I have just run into the same issue and manage to solve it after much head banging on the keyboard.

For ages, I've used my personal Gmail account (which is my Apple ID) for app development. It's always been linked to my organization's team.

However, I just realised my iTunes Connect account actually uses my work email.

When trying to sign the app in Xcode, it'd instead try to log into iTunes Connect using my personal email, which isn't actually linked to my organisation on iTunes Connect.

So, I just added my personal account to my team's iTunes Connect. Voila! All is well again. (I probably should've created an Apple ID for my work email and added that in Member Centre, but creating provisioning profiles is like getting stabbed in the eye).

Now I'm actually mind-boggled as to how it managed to work in the past.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue in Xcode 7.0.1 where we are packaging an app for a third-party to release. In the past, this has been no problem as our account has admin access and we have the required provisioning profiles.

However, in Xcode 7.0.1, I am receiving the same error 'No accounts with iTunes Connect access'. I tried the 'Technical User' fix mentioned above, but it did not have any effect.

I downloaded Xcode 7.1 beta 2 and the issue appears to have been fixed as I was able to build and package the app for third-party release. So, this seems as though it is a bug in Xcode that hopefully has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the app's version number (not the build number) - e.g. from 1.5 to 1.6.

None of the other answers were working for me, and this (inexplicably) solved it.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me while trying to submit from a coffee shop with spotty/restricted wi-fi. Application Loader also failed with an SSL-related error message.

If none of the above solutions work for you, I'd suggest simply trying from another wi-fi network.

Answer (score 0):

In my case internet was slow, so the problem was occurring. I changed network of my mac, the problem got solved.

Answer (score 0):

i find a solution, just open this link

https://appleid.apple.com/#!&page=signin

In the Security section, click Generate Password below App-Specific Passwords.

so now you have generated password, now open application loader and you email and generated password thats it now you can upload video on itune using application loader software.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Restart your computer

Restart Xcode

ReArchive your app

Remove and re add user

This worked for me after 2 hours of troubleshooting and even trying application loader. Not sure which one. But try a combination of this, and it might work.

Answer (score 0):

For around three weeks, i was unable to upload any of my apps to iTC. Apple just considered it a duplicate of an existing bug. I had tried the other methods suggested above.

It was eventually solved for me by downloading a new beta version of XCode (even though I was uploading from the release version), my guess is that this installed uploading tools that overwrote the ones I had been using?

Answer (score 0):

Close iTunes if open, worked for me.