# No accounts with iTunes Connect Access

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, itunes, application-loader

I'm trying to submit an app to the app store, the app was developed on my personal Apple ID and is being submitted on behalf of a third party (for which my Apple ID is an admin). I am getting an error stating that no iTunes Connect account can be found even though I have Admin/Legal rights.

What am I doing wrong? The app is being signed with their provisioning profile, etc

Comment: For me it was just a network problem. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39894093/3442758

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On Xcode 7 I keep receiving error "No accounts with iTunes connect access"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32592291/on-xcode-7-i-keep-receiving-error-no-accounts-with-itunes-connect-access)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Apple ID which you are using to upload the app; that Apple ID must be connected to both the portals (iTunesConnect and Developer) with the minimum roles given below:-

- Developer: Admin
- iTunesConnect: Admin/App manager/Developer

Answer (score 7):

Upload your app using application loader. I had the same problem and its working for me.

[How to upload App using application loader](https://help.swiftic.com/hc/en-us/articles/201574452-Upload-Your-App-to-iTunes-Connect-using-the-Application-Loader)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. My roles were correct on both Developer and iTunesConnect.
For me the solution was to remove my Apple-ID in Xcode, close and reopen Xcode and add the Apple-ID again. Afterwards I was able to upload via Archive Organizer.

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode 9.3 I'm finding that if I submit two apps back-to-back I see this issue with the second app. Closing and restarting Xcode fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Apple Developer Program Membership has not expired.