# Importing Developer Profile .developerprofile doesn't work. Still require password

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, provisioning-profile, ipa

I imported the Developer Profile **.developerprofile** to Xcode. But it still requires **password** for that account when I want to export **ipa** or **Upload to App Store**.

It happens for all accounts that I imported to the Xcode.

I tried to ask my client for export new **.developerprofile** file and it still can't be fixed.

Someday before, everything worked properly. I searched for hours but still stuck.

With the image below, the accounts with the mark (~) stop working. The middle account can work after I enter the password.

Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Are you using P12 ??

Comment: Possibly similar: [On Xcode 7 I keep receiving error “No accounts with iTunes connect access"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32592291/2108547)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figure out the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I figured out the problem.
My customer changed the password of the account that I imported. That why the Xcode ask the password every time I want to use.

To solve this, I requested my customer export for the new **.developerprofile** (match/have the new password)

For more information:

- With Code Signing Identity is "Developer", just need the developer **.p12** file. I can build and upload to App Store for Testflight.
- With Code Signing Identity is "Distribution", I have to use(import) **.developerprofile**.

Answer (score 4):

First, I'd remove and add those profiles once again. You can delete profile by tapping **minus** sign at the bottom of `Accounts` window.

Second - check `Keychain Access` and see if related accounts are included in your Keychain and all related Provisioning Profiles are not marked as *red*.

Finally, do remember that to **upload application to iTunesConnect** you need access to **iTunesConnect account** which may not be the same as **Developer Program** account - this is really common if you are handling several clients on one Developer Program account (meaning, using only one Apple ID) and use different iTunesConnect accounts - than you'll need to sign with them too using `Accounts` section in Xcode `Preferences`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figure out the problem

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it requires password i.e., your local system password. Whenever you export or upload it asks for system Password.

Allow keychain access here so that it store the password.

In the above account you just give apple id and apple password, no description is needed.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figure out the problem