# iTunes Connect access issue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, apple-watch, xcode7.3

When i tried uploading the app to the app store from Xcode 7.3.1, I am getting the following error "No accounts with iTunes connect access.  iTunes connect access for "APNA" is required. Add an account in the account preference pane".

FYI:
My apple ID account is been added as admin user to development team not in the associated iTunes connect.

I think my apple ID should be added as a one of the users the iTunes connect to upload the build to iTunes connect.

If yes,  what should be the user role on iTunes Connect?.  Can it be a developer/Admin enough to push the build to app store once the build is approved.

Can anyone please clarify me on the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On Xcode 7 I keep receiving error "No accounts with iTunes connect access"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32592291/on-xcode-7-i-keep-receiving-error-no-accounts-with-itunes-connect-access)

Comment: I tried deleting and adding the account in Xcode.  Need clarify on the following :  i am not able to access the iTunes connect of the development team where my ID is been added as admin.  Is it required to add the same ID to iTunes connect as one of the users to get access on iTunes Connect to upload the build ?