# On Xcode 8 Can't validate App, error "No account with iTunes connect access"

Tags: objective-c, app-store-connect, xcode8, submission

I am getting continuos issue while validating my app. In preferences of Xcode, i have added the accounts properly. Even i can build it on device. But can not validate the app for submission.

What is the solution ?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to delete al keys and provisioning profiles, add it with new generated and then build you app with signing manually instead of automaticly, this was the solution for me

Comment: Everything has been added newly. @LittleGnome

Comment: have u tried solutions provided in this link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32592291/on-xcode-7-i-keep-receiving-error-no-accounts-with-itunes-connect-access

Comment: Having the same problem after releasing a lot of times before. Workaround for now is using Xcode > OpenDeveloperTool > Application Loader, after exporting from the organizer. I remember last time, removing and adding the account worked, but now it still fails.