# How to upload ios app from xcode when invited to a developer team?

Tags: xcode, upload

I am working on an iOS app with a team that invited me to their developer account in order to upload the version from xcode 7.3.
The problem is I can access itunes connect normally but when I want to upload from xcode the account I was invited to is not showed.

Comment: If possible,  share the screenshot.

Comment: is this the issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32592291/on-xcode-7-i-keep-receiving-error-no-accounts-with-itunes-connect-access

Comment: Yes it is but it is not solved