# Xcode 9 "no iTunes Connect account" error when uploading

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

With a certain project in Xcode 9 beta 6 when I try to Upload to the App Store I get:

[image]

I am the "Admin" role for this account.

- All contracts are up-to-date
- I tried removing/re-adding my account from Xcode prefs several times
- Submitting for the same project from Xcode 8 works (however I need to upload from Xcode 9 for this project because it links against iOS 11 beta)

Another developer on the team is seeing the same thing so this seems like it might be common. Anyone find a workaround?

Comment: As of early October Apple seems to have worked all these issues out on the backend. Without updating Xcode lots of various issues like this have disappeared.

Comment: Hey brother the accepted answer should be https://stackoverflow.com/a/46279679/5332817

Answer (score 150, accepted):

I encountered the same issue with xCode 9 GM build and others reported it as well in xCode 10 and xCode 11. Deleting the derived data actually solved it for me. Hopefully it will help others as well.

1. Close xCode
2. `rm -fr ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`
3. Reopen xCode and try to upload again

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! It worked like a charm with XCode 9.0.1

Comment: Yes, that worked with Mac OS High Sierra and latest Xcode.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, worked for xcode 9.3

Comment: Switching this to the accepted answer since so many are reporting success. (I haven't run into this again since I wrote the Q.)

Comment: Is there any logic explanation why is derived data making difference for uploading archive to app store?

Comment: worked for me Xcode 9.4.1 (just thought i'd keep the thread going)

Comment: A year later, still the best solution. I don't even bother going to apple support forums now - stack has all the answers.

Comment: WTF! it worked xD Another thing wrong by apple i think

Comment: Thanks. But... why does this even work ! I can't see the relationship.

Comment: Cannot believe it that Xcode **11** suddenly gave me this error, and deleting derived data was the solution.

Answer (score 19):

This seems to be **issue with Xcode 9**. Solution is to **use Application Loader tool.**

**Step 1 : Create an IPA file**

1. Clean your project from Product -> Clean (cmd + shift + k )
2. Select Product -> Archive

   [image: Step1-2]
3. Once archive is successfully completed it will open in Organizer window
4. Press Export button present on right side

[image: Step3-4]

5. Now select the distribution method as per your need and click on Next button

[image: Step5]

6. This will show the App Store distribution options. Now click on Next button

[image: Step6]

7. Re-sign your project (preferred is Automatically manage signing) and click on Next button

[image: Step7]

8. There will be Review window containing IPA content details. Click on Export.

[image: Step8]

9. Now choose the location where folder is to be saved and Click on Export.

[image: Step9]

10. This will create an folder containing IPA, packaging.log, DistributionSummary.plist and ExportOptions.plist file

[image: Step10]

**Step 2 : Upload IPA using Application Loader**

1. Right click on Xcode tool present on Slide-bar. Goto Open Developer Tool -> Application Loader

[image: Step2-1]

2. This opens Application Loader. Press on Choose button and select IPA file.

[image: Step2-2]

3. This will analyse IPA file and will show IPA details. You can press on Activity button to see list of activity performed while uploading app. Click on Next.

[image: Step2-3]

4. This will create iTunes Connect API analysis file.

[image: Step2-4]

5. Once it is successfully uploaded it will show Success. Now click on Next.

[image: Step2-5]

6. You IPA file is submitted to AppStore successfully

[image: Step2-6]

Comment: I came to SO because I was having the same problem.  I had already solved it using Application Loader too, and wanted to share my success in case it wasn't already answered.  Seeing what you left, even though I had already solved my issue, I had to leave you an upvote because of your exhaustive and helpful answer for those that are unfamiliar with the export/AppLoader process.  Thank you for taking the time!

Comment: I was trying **1-** logout/login **2-** restart xcode **3-** remove derived data/restart **4-** full clean / rebuild / try to republish **5-** ....... and so on. Till I came to StackOverflow and i saw your answer which deserve THANK YOU for your time and effort to explain man :) .

Comment: I have upload my app (which is written in Objective C) through this steps , but not able to see this build on iTunes. what will be the issue?

Comment: @Ranjan : Your app will be visible when status is 'Ready for Sale'. If the status is 'Ready for Sale' and still not able to see on AppStore then wait for few hours (2 to 4) to appear. This happened with my case...had to wait for 2 hours. If still app dosen't appear then get in touch with Apple Support team.

Comment: Even unable to login to application loader. Apple seriously need to do something to make upload process smooth and to make it work on one go.

Comment: @Arun : Which version of Xcode / Application loader are you using?

Comment: Also having this issue @Arun - the team I want doesn't show in the list in the top left of Application Loader

Comment: @dan674 I am still struggling with login to application loader. The message i am getting is "Your apple id or password was entered incorrectly."

Comment: @dan674 : Maybe try after sometime or restart your system.

Answer (score 10):

The only solution I have found for now, is to generate IPA for AppStore and then upload it with Application Loader.

Comment: App Loader was the only solution here that worked for me. Xcode 8.3.2, directions here: http://help.apple.com/itc/apploader/#/apdS673accdb

Comment: This is just a work around, does not fix the actual issue.

Comment: Even unable to login to application loader. Apple seriously need to do something to make upload process smooth and to make it work on one go.

Answer (score 5):

I just had this happen to me and this was my solution.

1. Full Quit out of xCode 9
2. Reopen xCode
3. Update to a new version number
4. Archive again

Result: It worked

It's a pretty basic fix, but hopefully it will for you too.

Comment: This worked for me as well.  Seems to be an intermittent issue (maybe with the connection to iTunesConnect?)

Answer (score 3):

None of the mentioned answers helped me. Below I am mentioning what all I have tried to solve the issue but didn't work.

i) Check provisioning profile & Certificate combination.

ii) Clean

iii) Quit Xcode

iv) Delete derived data

v) Restart Xcode

**What worked for me is**

i) Open Xcode preferences

ii) Check iTunes account you are using. If it is already logged in, remove it.

iii) Login the iTunes account again

iv) Xcode will start process automatically once it gets access now.

v) Select the provisioning profile that you are using again while Xcode asks for it in the popup.

vi) Xcode will proceed upload process.

*This worked for me. Hope it will save some of your's time as well.*

Answer (score 1):

I just had a call with Apple developer customer support. They said its a known issue and the team is actively working on it. But there is no timeline insight.

Following solution that worked for me.
Use Xcode 8 until Apple engineers fix this issue:

**The solution may work even if you don't downgrade to Xcode 8**

Steps for Downgrading form Xcode 9 to Xcode 8

**1. Download Xcode 8 from:**
https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

**2. Install Xcode 8.**

**3. Create an ipa build**
In Xcode go to
Menu -> Product -> Archive -> Export

**4. Use the Application Loader to upload your ipa to iTunes connect**
Application Loader can be found at:
In Xcode go to
Xcode -> Open Developer Tools -> Application Loader

Let me know if it helped

Comment: Interesting. Unfortunately most of my apps use the iOS 11 SDK so I can't submit with Xcode 8.

Comment: You can do the same process using xcode 9. I have mentioned that downgrade may not be needed.

Answer (score 1):

The same case happened to me.
Also when I tried to get crash reports, it shows that my session has expired.

I have just restarted my Xcode and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In My case none of the above solutions worked,

I have an access for both Developer account and iTunes Connect account, but I faced the same Issue.

The only option worked for me is updating my MAC OS before it was 10.13.4, after update to 10.13.6 the problem was resolved. Hope this will help to someone.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it working by creating a new user in iTunes Connect, with just the "Developer" role.

For me, that also required to creating a new Apple ID.

I then added that new user in Xcode:

[image: Adding the new user in Xcode]

Now it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is to

1. remove the apple ID from the accounts known to XCode
2. to add the account again (do not import the account again)

See [On Xcode 7 I keep receiving error "No accounts with iTunes connect access"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32592291/on-xcode-7-i-keep-receiving-error-no-accounts-with-itunes-connect-access)

Comment: Thanks but as I listed in the original I've tried that and it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: For others looking for solutions:  Tried this with my Xcode 8.3, with no effect. Only by "exporting" a .ipa file and using Application Loader was I able to upload.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: This worked for me in Xcode 9 GM. I don't know if it will be an issue in the final version**

What worked for me is that I changed my regular AppleID email, with the equivalent @icloud.com alias.

For example, I didn't use `myemail@gmail.com`, I used `myemail@icloud.com` and it worked.

(Which I really don't prefer, I prefer using my personal email, but if it works, it works)

Comment: Could you elaborate on *where* you used this? That is, did you edit your apple ID at apple's website, or change your Xcode accounts list under Xcode preferences... etc?   I would like to try this, as nothing else has worked, but I'm unsure what to try changing.

Comment: @BillPatterson I used it to log in within Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts

Answer (score 0):

I could not use application loader because my password is not accepted. Even after changing my Apple ID password it was not accepted.

Restarting XCODE solved the upload problem this time. But it is a repetitive problem.

Apple is becoming a nightmare... XCode and iTunesConnect always have been...

Comment: yes its true,developement for apple has become such a crap

Answer (score 0):

I just removed and re-added my developer account for the Xcode 9. To remove account goto preferences -> select your account -> hit the minus icon(-). To add your account just click on the + icon next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the laptop fixed this. Didn't try restarting XCode itself, just rebooted the whole laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered with the same problem. But after I updated the Xcode to the current latest version of [Xcode 9.2](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-SW936) solved my problem. I took the update on [2017-12-21](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/RevisionHistory.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH99-SW1).

Answer (score 0):

For me remove derived data, clean project and try again working fine.

Please follow below steps:

1. Quit XCode
2. rm -fr ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
3. Reopen XCode and try to upload again

Hope it will help!

Answer (score 0):

Closed Xcode and reopened it.  This worked for me.  This was also the most popular answer on the apple forum.  Do this first.

Answer (score 0):

Your xCode must be open for longer time.

Quit the xCode and Reopen. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue fixed with below steps.
Just do Quit XCode completely even dock too then wait for few seconds and Reopen the Xcode then proceed to Archive again freshly.
then believe problem solve :). 
All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Solution that worked for me in Xcode 9.1

1. Go to Preferences.
2. Go to Accounts tab.
3. Select the desired account.
4. If there is a login expired error displayed, login again.
5. Make sure the error has gone away.
6. Restart Xcode.
7. Try to upload the archive again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me (after trying many times of signing-out and signing-in):

1. Sign out your Apple ID (by going to Preferences with `Cmd+,`)
2. Sign in with your Apple ID, and make sure you sign in with `***@icloud.com`
3. Somehow it all started working for me...

Posting it here in case it's helpful to anyone else. Have no clue how this solved the problem (and how the problem emerged in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's apple server error. So, wait for some time and then upload. It'll work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this is the problem of firewall when I connected to other network it's working.

Answer (score -1):

For me it helped to close Xcode and reopen it again, it was that simple ;)