# Xcode 8.3.3 "No accounts with iTunes Connect access"

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, xcode8

When trying to upload an App to iTunes connect in Xcode 8.3.3, I get the error:

> iTunes Connect access for "Team-Name" is required. Add an account in the  Accounts preference plane.

[image: Screenshot]

The account already exists and (in some cases) has been working without incident previously.

How do I get around this issue with Xcode so that I can upload my app to the AppStore?

Comment: And?  What happens when you add the account?

Comment: same here. We already remove the roles on both developer account and itunes connect: and adding it back again. Removing apple id and adding back again but it is still the dame.

Comment: Same here, I was going CRAZY!! Good to know that this is from Apple's side and that there is a fix. Thanks!

Comment: When i add it the issue persist @Paulw11

Comment: **Folks**, we don't need 100 "Yep, use application loader" answers below. If you don't have something substantive to add, pick an AL answer and upvote it.

Comment: Install the latest xcode. It should fix the problem! I hope it helps.

Comment: I was able to solved this issue by updating Xcode to the current latest version of  9.2 (updated date: 2017-12-22)

Comment: I had the same problem, the solution was RESTART XCODE

Comment: same here. a simple restart worked for me

Comment: I just experienced this and my solution was to close Xcode, reopen and retry it. I have no idea why this worked though!

Comment: Please check my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46009471/xcode-9-no-itunes-connect-account-error-when-uploading/50094406#50094406   This worked for me. Hope this will help you.

Comment: I believe this question should be re-opened - if you have the power to do so (>3000 rep I think), then please do; use the small grey "reopen" link under the question tags (beside "share" and "edit" links)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Had the same problem,
First had to export the .ipa to disk using XCode and then upload to the AppStore with Application Loader tool.

It worked.

Comment: Seems like Apple may have broken something. Can confirm exporting and using Application Loader works though

Comment: I cannot login on Application Loader even if my appId and password is correct.

Comment: Disable 2-factor auth as well.

Comment: I had to disable 2 factor auth as well before uploading with Application Loader.

Comment: Launch Xcode > Xcode menu > Open Developer Tool > Application Loader.

Comment: Application Loader won't let me sign in using my standard account info. Any suggestions on how I make this work? Thanks!

Comment: @mtkale Then how do I validate the archive before uploading?

Comment: You can validate using XCode's Build -> Archieve tool. There is a button on the right hand side "Validate".

Comment: @ibdakine - you have to go to https://appleid.apple.com and generate an app specific password to use with Application Loader.

Comment: Check this link might help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46685089/1753005

Comment: i have tried to upload using Application Loader but still getting error from Application loader  "The application account information was incorrect."

Comment: Started laughing, a single restart of Xcode fixed it for me :D

Comment: Restarting the Xcode did the job for me. First rule of IT, if something doesn't work, "Restart"

Answer (score 27):

I suspect that Apple has broken something with the IOS 11, etc upgrades going on. It was all working fine over the last few months, including yesterday, and suddenly today its broken.

As a temporary solution, I had to use export to local disk (from Archive), then select: XCode/Open Developer Tool/Application Loader.

Answer (score 19):

Had the same stupid problem.
Ultimately exported the .ipa to disk (via Xcode itself) and used `altool` command line tool to upload the ipa. It worked!!

```
altool --upload-app -f YourIpa.ipa -u <username>
```

Apple should really spend some $$$ on improving Xcode and the overall Developer experience. Its painful.

I again went back to Xcode to try and upload but met with the same error, so command line was indeed helpful.

Comment: Application loader asks for an app-specific password :(

Comment: Thank you the xcode upload to App store failed, but command line altool did uploaded successfully. Here the username=AppleID

Comment: @Valentin, just create an app specific password, then it works (for me at least...)!

Comment: @bLacKhoLE try "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/Versions/A/Support/altool"

Answer (score 18):

A restart to Xcode did the job for me

Comment: Yeah, I hope more people try this, it worked for me. I also did a quick clean of the project after I restarted and it's fine. CMD+Shift+K

Comment: You have to completely quit Xcode and then restart it to make it work. Merely closing the Xcode window won't work.

Answer (score 17):

I just spoke with an Apple rep, and he said I had to update to Xcode 9 GM and rebuild. After doing that, I was able to upload builds again.

Comment: worked for us as well. you need to answer a couple of new questions and finally the app uploads again...

Comment: Last time I had this issue, it was solved by updating Xcode. It has come back 6 months later, so I am just about to find out if that still works.

Answer (score 12):

On Xcode 9.3.3, a simple restart of Xcode fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 8):

This goes along with the other answers, eventually I had to export it and deliver the ipa with Application Loader.

**However, Application Loader didn't initially work for me.** I had to go into my apple id account ([appleid.apple.com](http://appleid.apple.com)) and add an [application specific password](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204397). Then I signed out of Application Loader and signed back in with the application specific password.

As far as I know, xCode doesn't let you sign in with an application specific password. My guess is that Apple broke authentication via regular passwords on their backend, but didn't break application specific ones.

Comment: I had a problem running the old version of Application Loader.  I had to run it from xCode->Open Developer Tool and then I didn't have to muck with my account.

Answer (score 8):

It works for me to follow the steps:

1. Archive the app with Xcode 8.3.3.
2. Upload to iTunes Connect with Xcode 9 GM.

Answer (score 4):

I started to panic this morning too, but then I remembered something like this happens every time a new iOS is released. Use Application Loader. Don't start changing certs/provisioning profiles. I'm sure Apple will fix soon. Plus Application Loader is super-easy to use. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

When nothing works. Just restart your computer and try again! Nonsense but works like magic.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: This worked for me in Xcode 9 GM. I don't know if it will be an issue in the final version**

What worked for me is that I changed my regular AppleID email, with the equivalent @icloud.com alias.

For example, I didn't use `myemail@gmail.com`, I used `myemail@icloud.com` and it worked.

(Which I really don't prefer, I prefer using my personal email, but if it works, it works)

Same answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46225187/4772647

Answer (score 0):

I did as some of you suggested, I used the Export function in Archive/Organizer to export an .ipa, then go to the Xcode application, use the Show Contents, then nav to "Application" and "Application Loader" and uploaded my app using Loader and that all worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when my app was rejected when uploading on AppStore (not sure if this could be connected).

I tried to remove and readd the Developer's account in XCode but that didn't help.

Then it started working after I replied to the Binary Rejected message on App Store Connect and restarted XCode.
Not sure if that could be connected but it started working again instantly after those steps.

Answer (score 0):

In My case none of the above solutions worked,

I have an access for both Developer account and iTunes Connect account, but I faced the same Issue.

The only option worked for me is updating my MAC OS before it was 10.13.4, after update to 10.13.6 the problem was resolved. Hope this will help to someone.